# How to solve $\mathrm {diag}(\mathsf Q^T\mathsf S\mathsf Q)=\mathsf 0$ for $\mathsf S$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am given a matrix $\mathsf P\in \mathbb R^{d\times m}$, $m\ge d+1$, and want to solve for a vector $\mathbf c\in \mathbb R^d$ and a real scalar $r$. From these I construct
$$\mathsf Q\in \mathbb R^{n\times m} = \begin{vmatrix}\mathsf{P}\\
\mathsf{1}
\end{vmatrix}\quad\textrm{where }n=d+1
$$ and 
$$
\mathsf S\in \mathbb S_ {\textrm {--}}^n = 
\begin{vmatrix}
 -\mathsf I  & \mathbf c \\
\mathbf {c} & f\left( r,\mathbf {c}\right )
\end{vmatrix}
$$
and obtain the vector equation 
$$\mathrm {diag}(\mathsf Q^T\mathsf S\mathsf Q)=\mathsf 0\quad (1)$$
that I want to solve for $\mathsf S$.

I have found $\mathbf c$ and $r$ for $d=2$ and $m=3$ by analysis, and with them found $\mathsf Q^T\mathsf S\mathsf Q$ for this case. The matrix did indeed have zeros on the diagonal, but otherwise the pattern to its structure eluded me. I tried LU decomposition, but that did not provide any insight.

I thought there might be some linear transformation that could be applied to $\mathsf Q$ to yield $\mathsf S$ that satisfies $(1)$.

How do I solve the equation in the general case?

Answer (score 1):

You can start by expanding $\mathbf Q^T\mathbf S\mathbf Q$ blockwise. $$\begin{align}
\mathbf Q^T\mathbf S\mathbf Q &= \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf P\\\mathbf1^T\end{bmatrix}^T \begin{bmatrix}-\mathbf I&\mathbf c\\\mathbf c^T&f(r,\mathbf c)\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf P\\\mathbf1^T\end{bmatrix} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf P^T&\mathbf1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}-\mathbf P+\mathbf c\mathbf1^T\\\mathbf c^T\mathbf P+f(r,\mathbf c)\mathbf1^T\end{bmatrix} \\
&= -\mathbf P^T\mathbf P+\mathbf P^T\mathbf c\mathbf1^T+\mathbf1\mathbf c^T\mathbf P+f(r,\mathbf c)\mathbf1\mathbf1^T.
\end{align}$$
So
$$\operatorname{diag}(\mathbf Q^T\mathbf S\mathbf Q) = -\operatorname{diag}(\mathbf P^T\mathbf P)+2\mathbf P^T\mathbf c+f(r,\mathbf c)\mathbf1 = 0,$$
which is a linear equation in $\mathbf c$ and $f(r,\mathbf c)$.

Comment: Ah, that helps! Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm, should the last term be $$f\left(r,\mathbf c\right)\mathsf 1$$?

Comment: You're right, somehow I was thinking of $\operatorname{tr}(\mathbf1\mathbf1^T)$ instead of $\operatorname{diag}(\mathbf1\mathbf1^T)$ there.